# Objects with same class do not hide sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fadeOut the blue circle markers on click. It works on the first few clicks but after that the markers do not fade out. What can I be doing wrong?

Here is a **[demo](http://solidopinion.dev.limusdesign.com/)**. Please look for the animated circle blue markers.

P.S: I am trying to fadeout the objects with the class of `.marker`.

```
var marker = $('.marker'),
    body = $('#movingBody'),
    dynamicbox = $('.dynamicbox'),
    dbleft = $('.dynamicbox.left').hide(),
    dbright = $('.dynamicbox.right').hide(),
    closeBtn = dynamicbox.find('.close');

marker.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        rel = $this.attr('rel'),
        div = $(rel),
        img = $this.attr('href');

    marker.fadeOut(200);    
    $('.dynamicbox .content div').hide();
    div.show();
    $(img).fadeIn();

    function animateOut(unit) {
        body.animate({
            'left' : unit
        }, 500, 'easeOutCirc');
    }

    if($this.hasClass('r')) {
        animateOut(0); dbright.fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        animateOut(258); dbleft.fadeIn(200);
    }

    closeBtn.on('click', function() {
        body.animate({
            'left' : 140
        }, 500, 'easeOutCirc', function() {
            marker.fadeIn(200);
        });
        $(img).fadeOut();
        dynamicbox.fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: The "first few clicks" of what? Also, please post demonstrations of your problems somewhere like [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), where we can easily see the code, and what's happening, without having to dig through the rest of your site (please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it for guidance on that).

Comment: How to reproduce the error ?

Comment: Go to his demo link and click the blue circles a few times.

Comment: Keep opening and closing the markers by clicking on them blue animated circles. After a few tries, you will see that they do not disappear sometimes.

Comment: @David I can post my HTML & CSS too if it would help. It would be pretty difficult to create a jsFiddle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving this part outside the 'click' function:

```
 closeBtn.on('click', function() {  
     ...
 });
```

Comment: Awh Man! I think that might have fixed it!

Comment: Yup, seems to be the fix. Thanks!